# vb.net drawing program - how to erase pen

Tags: vb.net, pen

So I am creating a painting program, which uses the system drawing pen tool. How can I make an erasure tool, though?

Its in VB.NET

Or how can I make an undo feature? So it undo's the latest drawing. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would think that an erase operation would be identical to a draw operation but just using the color of the canvas.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, that would be the best way. Though my canvas is not one single color..

Answer (score 0):

For each type of drawing item make a class that holds the properties required for it; color, x, y, etc... Then when they are drawn store them in a collection. Then the Undo feature removes the last element. When drawing you just need to iterate the collection.

Like `@Chris Dunaway` stated, the erase feature is a pen of the same color as the canvas.